# How to subscribe to an event fired from a component

Tags: angular, events, components

I need to subscribe to the event I have just emitted.

"Something else" needs to "Does something 1" be finished, but I know that Event Emmiter is not subscribeable. Is there any other architecture or communication to do this?

Thank you very much

```
 export class MyClass { 
     returnMethod(){
     //Does something 1
     }
 }

export class Component
    @Output() returnMethod : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    operation(){
       //Does something 2
       this.returnMethod.emit();
       //Something else
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declar a `Subject` type variable in your service and push data by calling `.next()` and then catch that in your other class where want to catch data.

export class MyClass {  //(has a service instance)
     result: new Subject();

```
 constructor () {
   this.result.next('fired first result');
 }
 returnMethod(){
  //Does something 1
  this.result.next('fired returnMethod result');
 }
```

}

Now you can catch that here by subscribing the result.

```
// normally this is a component if angular is in context
export class myComponent {
    // normally @output being used in component
    @Output() returnMethod : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private muClass: MyClass) {  // this will inject the service

    operation(){
       //Does something 2
       this.myclass.result.subscribe((res) => {
         //Something else
       });
       // this is a output variable and can be emitted if there is a child component.
       this.returnMethod.emit();

    }
```

Comment: did it work? if its parent child then you can also use @output variable and then emit and catch that in a different way

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subject instead, I think Event Emitters are primarily for for Component Child-Parent communication.

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    doSomething(myParam: string) {
        this.subject.next({ myParam: myParam});
    }

    getSubscription(): Observable<any> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

And then your component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
    subscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        // subscribe to home component messages
        this.subscription = 
        this.myService.getSubscription().subscribe(param=> { this.returnMethod(param.param });
    }

   returnMethod(param){
        //do your thing
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // unsubscribe to ensure no memory leaks
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```